# Travis build takes longer than 50min -> kill

Tags: c++, unix, ubuntu-14.04, travis-ci

I have problem, that I need to install boost1.58 + latest HDF5 + other libraries from source (because trusty has no recent version of them)
to build the [project](https://github.com/gabyx/GRSFramework) on travis.

Installing all manually takes more then 50min which makes travis kill the job. What can I do to reduce or maybe increase the build time?
Either I need a way to install packages from versions > Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
or somehow use the travis cache (how??)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

My experience with boost is that the problem isn't the size, it's the number of files. You can create a minimal subset of boost using bcp:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html

Once everything is installed, are you doing your build in parallel, such as `make --jobs`? There are only 2 CPUs on a Travis VM, but this can cut your build time dramatically.

We also experimented with Travis dependency caching, but it just creates a tar file and so didn't give us any improvement. It may be useful if the download time for any of the libraries is significant due to a slow connection.
https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/

Comment: My build now takes about 52 minutes (with two cores, assumed) and gets killed by travis... hm... Do I really need to resort to differetn branches which compile different stuff? hm...

Comment: Ah I think I can do that with the build matrix in Travis

Comment: taring up the /usr/local  where boost is installed is not a good idea for caching?

Comment: boost is already distributed as a tar file, so the only reason to re-tar it would be is if you can download it from S3 substantially faster than you can download it from its official download site.

Comment: I build boost -> cache the libs and includes and reuse that in a next build
as I found out caching sudo required directories does not work in travis:
so i copy `/usr/local` into the home dir and cache that one as specified in `.travis.yml`.

Answer (score 1):

libboost1.60-all-dev is whitelisted in https://raw.githubusercontent.com/travis-ci/apt-package-whitelist/master/ubuntu-precise so it stands to reason that it's avaliable from one of the additional sources listed in https://raw.githubusercontent.com/travis-ci/apt-source-whitelist/master/ubuntu.json

Answer (score 1):

You can try caching your build artifacts (the intermediate directory with .o files) as well as the mtimes of the source files. Since they change only very rarely, the they won't get rebuilt every time.

[mtime_cache](https://github.com/iboB/mtime_cache) is a tool which can help you with the mtime cache, while Travis CI's cache can take care of the rest.